# Android FloatingActionButton “onclick” does not work

Tags: java, android

Estoy tratando de que los botones flotantes de **"new_tanda_id"** y **"cancel_tanda_id"** respondan al evento `onClick` definido en su diseño XML *(android:onClick= "NombreDelMetodo")* pero no hacen nada. ¿Alguna posible solución?

Cree una **basic_activity**, por esa razón tengo 2 layout (que serían el activity_main y el content_main) pero yo lo que sé es que solo se puede crear desde **XML** un `FloatingActionButton` desde el **activity_main** y NO del *content_main*.

***activity_cargas_descargas.xml***

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/new_tanda_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onAddNewTanda"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_new_tanda"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#263238" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/cancel_tanda_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:onClick="onDeleteNewTanda"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menos_tanda"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#263238"
        android:focusable="true" />
```

***content_cargas_descargas.xml***

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:id="@+id/scroll_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".cargas_descargas"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_cargas_descargas">



    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/parent_layout_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >






    <LinearLayout

        android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_primer_tupla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00b0ff"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tandas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:text="Tanda N°:"
            android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_horizontal_segunda_tupla"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorControlHighlight"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/articulos"
            android:layout_width="155dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Artículos"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/img_carga"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_carga" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cargas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:text="Carga"
            android:textSize="15sp" />


        <ImageView

            android:id="@+id/img_descarga"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_descarga" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descargas"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="Descarga"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

    </LinearLayout>




    </LinearLayout>     <!-- Fin del "parent_layout_vetical" -->



</ScrollView>
```

TIENE PRÁCTICAMENTE EL MISMO CÓDIGO QUE *content_cargas_descargas.xml*

MainActivity ***cargas_descargas.java***:

```
public class cargas_descargas extends AppCompatActivity {

    /************** DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES GLOBALES***********/

    /*Declaración de variable de tipo LinearLayout para implementarla como contenedor padre de los demás LinearLayoutHorizontales.*/
    private LinearLayout LinearLayoutNuevaTanda;

    private ScrollView parent_scrollView;


    int tanda_numero = 1;

    /*Variable entera para identificar a cada tupla que se crea programáticamente con cada
    click del botón "+" */
    int id = -1;

    ImageButton btnAddArtXML;
    ImageButton btnMenosArtXML;

    private FloatingActionButton fab_nueva_tanda;


    /*Declaración de variables tipo Spinner que contiene los artículos correspondientes y una matríz de tipo cadena que contendrá
     los nombres de dichos artículos. Por el momento, serán un total de 6 artículos*/
    Spinner spinner_tercer_tupla_xml, sp_new_art_xml, sp_nueva_tanda, spinner_new_tanda_Programatico;
    String[] datos = {"Bidones", "Dispenser Plástico", "Canillas", "Dispenser Eléctrico", "Envases rotos/pinchados", "Envases estropeados"};


    /*Declaración de variables tipo EditText para que representan las cargas y descargas de artículos y dinero con respecto a la tanda del XML.*/
    EditText eTcantCarga;
    EditText eTcantDescarga;
    EditText eTcantMoneyCarga;
    EditText eTcantMoneyDescarga;


    /*****************************COMIENZO DEL OnCreate********************************************/


    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cargas_descargas);

        parent_scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_parent);

        LinearLayoutNuevaTanda = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout_vertical);



        /*Inicialización de la variable de tipo TextView creada en XML para hacer referencia al número de tanda en el que estamos parados */
        TextView textViewTanda = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tandas);
        textViewTanda.setText("Tanda N°: " + tanda_numero);
        tanda_numero++;

        /*Inicialización de variable del botón "+" para añadir un nuevo artículo*/
        btnAddArtXML = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add_art);

        /**Método para añadir nuevos artículos pero que deberá cumplir ciertas condiciones para que se cumpla dicha acción**/
        btnAddArtXML.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            } /*Fin del método OnClick*/

        }); /**Fin del método setOnClickListener**/


        spinner_tercer_tupla_xml = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_art);

        /*Inicialización de los campos de carga y descarga de artículos y dinero en el diseño XML*/
        eTcantCarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_carga);
        eTcantCarga.requestFocus();

        eTcantDescarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_descarga);

        eTcantMoneyCarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_carga_money);

        eTcantMoneyDescarga = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtx_descarga_money);


        /*Llamada a la función: */
        setSpinner(spinner_tercer_tupla_xml, eTcantCarga);


        /*Inicialización de un FloatingActionButton para AÑADIR una nueva tanda*/
        fab_nueva_tanda = findViewById(R.id.new_tanda_id);
        /*Inicialización de un FloatingActionButton para ELIMINAR una nueva tanda*/
        final FloatingActionButton fab_cancel_tanda = findViewById(R.id.cancel_tanda_id);


        /* Llamada a la función: */
        //LeerValorSharedPreferences();


        /*Inicialización del Toolbar */
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        /**Método para añadir una nueva tanda solo si se guardan los cambios en la primer tanda**/
        fab_nueva_tanda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*Llamada a la función: */

                //onAddNewTanda(view);


                /*Propiedades que permiten esconder el fab de añadir nueva tanda y de hacer visible
                al fab de eliminar tanda*/
                fab_nueva_tanda.setVisibility(GONE);
                fab_cancel_tanda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                /*Mensaje una vez añadida la nueva tanda*/
                Snackbar.make(view, "Nueva tanda añadida", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

            }/*Fin del método onClick*/
        }); /**Fin del método setOnClickListener */


        /**Método para eliminar una tanda**/
        fab_cancel_tanda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /*Llamada a la función: */

                //onDeleteNewTanda(view);



                /*Una vez que se elimine la tanda, el botón para añadir una nueva tanda se hará visible,
                mientras que el boton de cancelar tanda se esconderá*/
                fab_cancel_tanda.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fab_nueva_tanda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                /*Si eliminamos una nueva tanda...*/
                tanda_numero--;


                /*Mensaje una vez añadida la nueva tanda*/
                Snackbar.make(view, "Tanda eliminada", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


            } /*Fin del método OnClick*/
        });/**Fin del método setOnClickListener**/


    } /********FIN DEL MÉTODO OnCreate********/




    /********FUNCION DODNE LE PASAMOS COMO PARAMETROS LOS 4 SPINNER EXISTENTES Y SUS RESPECTIVOS EDITTEXT'S DE CARGA********/

    public void setSpinner (final Spinner spinner, final EditText EditTextCarga){

        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_tandas, datos);
        spinner.setAdapter(adaptador);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {


            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Toast to = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ha seleccionado " + text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                to.show();

                if (text == "Envases rotos/pinchados" || text == "Envases estropeados") {

                    EditTextCarga.setEnabled(false);
                    EditTextCarga.setHint("");

                } else {

                    EditTextCarga.setEnabled(true);
                    EditTextCarga.setHint("Cantidad");

                }



            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

    }   /*************************************FIN DE LA FUNCION setSpinner()*****************************/



public void onAddNewTanda(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    final View NewTandaView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nueva_tanda, null);

    int VariablePrueba = LinearLayoutNuevaTanda.getChildCount();

    LinearLayoutNuevaTanda.addView(NewTandaView, VariablePrueba  -1);
}



    public void onDeleteNewTanda(View v) {


        LinearLayoutNuevaTanda.removeView((View) v.getParent());


    }

}
```

Creo que eso es todo el código. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas definiendo un método a ser llamado mediante el botón a través de `android:onClick`:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/new_tanda_id"
    ...
    ...
    android:onClick="onAddNewTanda"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/cancel_tanda_id"
    ...
    android:onClick="onDeleteNewTanda"
    />
```

No es necesario crear un listener, simplemente definir en código el método que defines en el botón.

No definas `OnClickListener` para los botones, únicamente crea los métodos a llamar definidos en el layout que serían `onAddNewTanda` y `onDeleteNewTanda`, estos serán llamados al dar clic en los botones:

```
private void onAddNewTanda(View view){

                fab_nueva_tanda.setVisibility(GONE);
                fab_cancel_tanda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


                /*Mensaje una vez añadida la nueva tanda*/
                Snackbar.make(view, "Nueva tanda añadida", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();


}

private void onDeleteNewTanda(View view){


               /*Una vez que se elimine la tanda, el botón para añadir una nueva tanda se hará visible,
                mientras que el boton de cancelar tanda se esconderá*/
                fab_cancel_tanda.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                fab_nueva_tanda.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                /*Si eliminamos una nueva tanda...*/
                tanda_numero--;


                /*Mensaje una vez añadida la nueva tanda*/
                Snackbar.make(view, "Tanda eliminada", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();

}
```